# Is there any way to redirect on view using routes in CI (HMVC)?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Now CI using this format to call a view page :

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Auth/login/index';
```

Is there any to direct call for view page.

Comment: No. via MVC/HMVC route goes to the controller and then to view or model according to code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. 
You cant directly access view pages ( application/views/..). As CI is an MVC based framework every request should go through an index.php file -> Controller -> Method.